# Javascript | Can't replace \n with String.replace()

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, replace

I have code which parse web-site and take information from database.
It's look like this:

```
var find = body.match(/\"text\":\"(.*?)\",\"date\"/);
```

As result, I have:

> гороскоп на июль скорпион\nштукатурка на газобетон\nподработка на день\nмицубиси тюмень\nсокращение микрорайон

Then i try to replace \n, but it's don't working.

```
var str = find[1].replace(new RegExp("\\n",'g'),"*");
```

What I can do with this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you want to replace the text `\n`, i.e. a backslash followed by an `n`, as opposed to a newline character.

In which case you can try

```
var str = find[1].replace(/\\n/g, "*");
```

or the less readable version

```
var str = find[1].replace(new RegExp("\\\\n", "g"), "*");
```

In regular expressions, the string `\n` matches a newline character.  To match a backslash character we need to 'escape' it, by preceding it with another backslash.  `\\` in a regular expression matches a `\` character.  Similarly, in JavaScript string literals, `\` is the escape character, so we need to escape both backslashes in the regular expression again when we write `new RegExp("\\\\n", "g")`.

Comment: Hi. I've tried the both solution and it seems there's a difference between them. The first doesn't work, but the second yes?!
Is someone could explain me why?

Answer (score 2):

Working in the console!

Here this works globally and works on both types of line breaks:

```
find[1].replace(/\r?\n/g, "*")
```

if you dont want the '\r' to be replaced you could simply remove that from the regex.

Comment: [code](http://i.piccy.info/i9/88550a96d591b8c1a755811c13b325d5/1475438227/154002/1028497/Screen_Shot_2016_10_02_at_22_57_15.png)
 | [result](http://i.piccy.info/i9/38499e9bb8ca1e055993a43f4bd3e901/1475438268/40163/1028497/Screen_Shot_2016_10_02_at_22_57_08.png) p.s. Sorry for Russian, it's website data.

Comment: interesting, I just tried in my chrome console and it works fine. Here is a screenshot - http://imgur.com/a/3W72C

Could you show me the exact output you get when you console.log find[1]?

Comment: I think it's something like a parsing-shield on this website. Because this code works with another websites. log -> [this](http://i.piccy.info/i9/47ac46a943613108595de055fdfb5116/1475440895/55704/1028497/scr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

removes all 3 types of line breaks

`let s = find[1].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " - ")`