# str.replace() method is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to replace all the occurrences of \n into 
 tags in the string which I want to show in HTML. Seems like it's not working as expected. It is not replacing any \n from a string. Just to inform, I am fetching the text from API.

some.component.html

```
 <p  class="notes-desc"
        [innerHTML]="replaceHtml(note.noteDesc) | safeHTML"
      ></p>
```

some.component.ts

```
 replaceHtml(text) {
    if (!text || !text.length) {
      return text;
    }
    console.log(text);
    const textFrm = text.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
    console.log(textFrm);
    return textFrm;
  }
```

[image: This is the output on the console]

Comment: `text.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>")` should replace `\n` with `<br/>`. What did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: I am not getting any replaced string in the output through this method. But if I try the same thing on the chrome dev console. It is working as expected

Comment: Not sure what's at fault, sorry. Have you tried removing the pipe?

Comment: Are you sure it's a new line and not a carriage return?? Try using the `\r` too. Additionally try turning off the Dom sanitization in it's entirety in your method , see ref : https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: Hi sir, I tried \r too. It is not working. could not find any diff. There is no issue with the pipe. After removing the pipe, still, the texts display the same.

Comment: Does your string contain a single newline character (i.e. `\n`) *or* does it contain the literal string `"\n"` (a backslash and an "n")? You are replacing the newline, if you intend to replace the literal string you need to escape the backslash: `/\\n/g`

Comment: can you reproduce your issue here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vv621x

Comment: @rickdenhaan Thank you for your help. Putting /\\n/g has fixed the issue. Could you please tell me what was happening behind the scenes?

Comment: @ROHITSHARMA `\n` is used to replace a newline character. `\\n` is used to replace the two separate characters `\ ` and `n`. The text you received from the API does not contain newlines but the separate characters.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Got it. Thank you so much for your explanation. I spend almost 1 hour on this issue and you saved the rest of my time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript | Can't replace \n with String.replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820929/javascript-cant-replace-n-with-string-replace)

Answer (score 0):

You Just Need to Use `innerText` rather than `innerHtml` .
Try This Code .

`function myCallback(response){
        var response_div = document.getElementById("response_div");
        response_div.innerText = JSON.parse(response).stringOutput;
}`

It Served the same purpose You were Expecting